# Razorpay payment with promo code

Tags: payment-gateway, promotion-code

What is the way to use promo code concept in Razorpay?

Note 1: Razorpay payment works on client side.

Note 2: Promo code can be applied only once.

Note 3: How to manage two parallel payments with promo code applied? (Accept one payment and stop another payment without deducting amount from bank.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor pay deals only with payment

promocode has nothing to do with it

you should start payment only after the promocode logic is executed